# Reactivity trigger for Watching computed properties in Vue

Tags: vue.js

Normally when working with Vue, I expect the callback for a watched property to be triggered only when the value of that property changes. However, a colleague noticed that this does not seem to hold when watching computed properties, as can be demonstrated by the following example:

```
  <div id = "demo">
    {{ numbers }} </br>
    {{ evenNumbers }}
  </div>

<script src="./vue.js"></script>
<script>
var demo = new Vue({
    el: '#demo',
    data: function(){
        return {
        numbers: [1,2,3,4,5,6]
      };
    },
    computed: {
      evenNumbers: function () {
            return this.numbers.filter(x => (x % 2 == 0))
        }
    },
    watch: {
      evenNumbers: function (val) {
         alert("yes, computed property changed")
       }
    }
})

setTimeout(() => { demo.numbers.push(7) }, 5000)
</script>
```

After 5s, the alert is displayed, but the value of the computed numbers array doesn't change. It's tempting to infer that the watcher is triggered if the dependencies of the computed property update, even when the computed property itself doesn't.

It turns out that this suits us fine for the application we're working on, but I don't understand the behaviour, and I don't know if we can rely on it, or under what conditions it will hold. (For example, I have two arrays here, but would it still work if I had primitives involved instead? I have no idea, and I might experiment if I have time, but issues with comparing object equality were just the first thing that occurred to me as I typed this, and the pitfalls with Vue's reactivity and composite objects were the second.) I'd also imagine it might be an unpleasant surprise if the callback to your watcher were an expensive operation.

If anyone could explain how this works, and if we can rely on this behaviour, I'd be grateful.

Comment: You might find [this](https://github.com/numbbbbb/read-vue-source-code/blob/master/04-dynamic-data-observer-dep-and-watcher.md#watcher) helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time `evenNumbers()` is executed, it generates an entirely new array. Since arrays are compared by equality of reference, they can never be equal. The only way to properly detect this change is to manually compare the contents of the previously calculated array to the newly calculated one.

Example, using lodash:

```
import { isEqual } from 'lodash';
...
watch: {
    evenNumbers(newValue, oldValue) {
        if(!isEqual(newValue, oldValue) {
            alert('callback')
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The watcher was triggered because it had no way of knowing whether the change on `data.numbers` will affect the result of `computed.evenNumbers`.

However, upon recalculating, it discovers that 7 is not even, so the array remains `[2, 4, 6]`.

If you want to make sure the callback only runs when the value actually changes, you can designate it like

```
watch: {
  evenNumbers(newValue, oldValue){
    if(newValue !== oldValue) {
      alert('callback')
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I would have expected it to treat the result of the computation like any other data- after all, it must still do this for this suggestion to work. But the suggestion is helpful, so thanks

Comment: Every time evenNumbers() is executed, it generates an entirely new array. Since arrays are compared by equality of reference, they can never be equal. The only way to properly detect this change is to manually compare the contents of the previously calculated array to the newly calculated one.

Comment: You are right, Mattias. There are methods in underscore or lodash that will do the proper equality check for you.

Comment: @MattiasMartens Just looked at this again- happy to make your observation an accepted answer if you want

Comment: Thanks @rwold — I've posted my comment as an answer.